# How does MongoRepository finds the correct collection when findById(String id) is called?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, reflection

I'm trying to understand a little more about how does Spring finds the correct Collection when calling the `findById(String id)` method.
Normally the classes that will be persisted are annotated with `@Document(collection = "CollectionName")`
and when a basic operation like:

```java
T save(T entity);
Optional<T> findByExample(T entity);
T update(T entity);
```

Seem kinda understandable that we can access the annotation data since we have the whole entity available, but when a method like:

```java
T findById(String id)
```

We don't have access to the entity information, the closer we get is the Generic type `T`.
But only with the type `T` we are not able to initialize a new object and get the annotations information.
There is any documentation available that explains this?

Comment: Is the type information maybe stored in the database?

Comment: I tough about it, but let's say a database has multiple Collections/Tables.. how one's decide where to persist/retrieve the data?